# Weighted Average of several raster "zones"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst

Suppose I have two rasters, A and B. I want to determine the value of a certain "zone" in raster A by taking the weighted average of several other zones from raster B, that partially overlay onto that zone of raster A.

I think its much better if I show you a picture to try to explain:

[image]

- The "certain 'zone' in raster A" is shown as the teal polygon in the border, suppose it is rasterized and is made up of 1000 cells.
- The red grids are the "several other zones from raster B." In this case, there are four denoted by g1, g2, g3, g4 (these are some values).
- The weight will be determined by the number of pixels lying within the respective zones in raster B.
- The value of that certain 'zone' in raster A will be determined by this:

  **value of zone in A = (50/1000)g1 + (300/1000)g2 + (150/1000)g3 + (500/1000)g4**

I've thought of employing the Combine tool in ArcMap and then bringing it into excel.. but it is a fairly manual process. I have a lot of data to get through (like 50+ raster B's that I must aggregate through)..

Is there an easier way to do this? Is there a specific function you think may help?
I have little experience in writing a python script but if you point me to some packages+functions in arcpy or numpy or whatnot, I'd greatly appreciate it.

====

edit: Similar, previous questions have suggested things like "dasymmetric mapping" like this thread: [Using National Agriculture Statistics Service (NASS) county level crop data to estimate crop acreage in hydrologic regions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/how-to-use-nass-county-level-crop-data-to-estimate-crop-acreage-in-hydrologic-re/6559#6559).. which suggests the use of the Intersect tool, but I'd generally prefer to rely on using weights from the counts of defined cell sizes of a raster rather than have arcgis calculate the area proportions from vector data.

I also found a helpful tip on this question, [Obtain normalized raster average per polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43191/obtain-normalized-raster-average-per-polygon), suggesting Zonal Statistics. Is the "mean" of Zonal Statistics the same as what I'm trying to do? I'll try it and report back...

Comment: Couldn't you clip the polygon out and calculate the average?

Comment: ..hmm, but I have much more than one polygon

Comment: Could you describe the desired output in more detail?  Is Raster B simply defining the zones, or are you interested in the pixel values of raster B too?  Can't you complete this analysis using Zonal statistics via your teal polygon and raster B?  Thanks for clearing this up.