# Clipping and Reduce Region vs Reduce region alone gives different results

Tags: google-earth-engine

Here is the [sample code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/38b96132bb4509d136a3752bda1f2cd1).

I filtered CHIRPS dataset for a year, computed total rainfall in the year using Reducer.sum() and before and after clipping it to a geometry. The pixel values are equal if you go to the inspector. However, when I use reduceRegion to compute average areal average rainfall, the two images give different results.

In fact, when I clip to the geometry first, the total rainfall is lower than the original. I think when I clip, some of the pixels get omitted. Can anyone explain what's going on here and which method should I use?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the in GEE documentation (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reducer-sum?hl=en), **ee.Reducer.sum()** and **ee.Reducer.mean** are weighted reducers. Some ideas, if you dont know it already, about weighted mean on rasters are here [Weighted Average of several raster "zones"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59321/weighted-average-of-several-raster-zones).

Basically, you apply a weighted reducer on an already weighted reduced dataset. As in the image uploaded (sorry for this bad graphic) the difference between the final results, **total** and **total_clipped** in your sample code, is based on the fact that your first mean (**total**) takes in the considerations the weighted sum of the whole raster. The second mean(**total_clipped**) takes in consideration only the weighted sum of the clipped raster. So the blue part, as a weight from the raster, is missing even if you reduce on the same region.

[image]